# How does titlesec call sectionbreak implicitly?

Tags: macros, sectioning, titlesec

How does package `titlesec` work?
I have never called `\sectionbreak` explicitly in my code, but it appears `\sectionbreak` is called in between `\section`

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage \setcounter{equation}{0}}

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=3.99      \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \pi^2=9.86    \end{equation}

\section{Two}
\begin{equation} E=mc^2        \end{equation}
\begin{equation} v=\frac{e}{t} \end{equation}

\subsection{Two \& One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=22 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to page 8 pf the [titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) manual, `\sectionbreak` is applied after each section command. If you wander through the package code, in`titlesec.sty`, then you will find two instances of:

```
\@ifundefined{#6break}%
  {\addpenalty{\@secpenalty}}%
  {\csname#6break\endcsname}%
```

Here, `#6` the the name of sectioning command, so one of `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, `paragraph` or `subparagraph`. In the special case when `#6` is `section` the code above says:

> if `sectionbreak` is not defined then add a `\@secpenalty` penalty and
> if it is defined then add `\sectionbreak`

If you want to see this happening when you compile you file then, for example, you can add `\typeout{Adding a section break!!!}` to the definition of the `\sectionbreak` command (see below), and then look in the log file - in compile the file in the terminal and look at the output.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand{\sectionbreak}{\clearpage \setcounter{equation}{0}\typeout{Adding a section break!!!}}

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=3.99      \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \pi^2=9.86    \end{equation}

\section{Two}
\begin{equation} E=mc^2        \end{equation}
\begin{equation} v=\frac{e}{t} \end{equation}

\subsection{Two \& One}
\begin{equation} 2+2=22 \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Albeit the guideline, I really want to say Thank you!!